# Cómo asignar tipo a las variables de un CTE en SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Tengo un código como este:

```
declare @r bigint=1;
select @r*=n from (select top(15) number+1n from master..spt_values where type='P')t
```

Calcula el factorial de un número. Lo he intentado replicar con una CTE recursiva, pero me desborda debido al tipo de los parámetros:

```
with fact(F, n) as (
select 1,15
union all
select F*n,n-1 from fact where n>1
)select F from fact 
where n=1 option(maxrecursion 0)
```

Hay forma de indicarle que el parámetro F sea bigint.

El caso es que cuando trato de calcular el factorial de 15, supera el tamaño de int y da error de desbordamiento. He intentado hacer un cast a bigint pero no me ha funcionado. ¿Es posible indicarle un tipo a los parámetros de un CTE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El tipo de dato, viene asignado por la primera fila de la unión de los conjuntos.

Si quieres usar **bigInt**, entonces la primera fila debe de devolver tipos `bigint`:

```
with fact(F, n) as (
select CAST(1 AS bigint), CAST(15 AS bigint)
union all 
select F*n,n-1 from fact where n>1
)select F from fact 
where n=1 option(maxrecursion 0);
```

[image: Res1]

Comment: Perfecto Javi, eso era justo lo que necesitaba saber. Muchísimas gracias.

Comment: @JoséManuel si la respuesta te sirvio marcala como aceptada